# Is there a way to make a spam download button in html and js?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, download

I want to have a button on my website, and when the user presses that button, it downloads infinite files, until they close the page, or the computer crashes. I want to do this with a loop,is there a way that I could do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function(){window.location = 'http://download.winzip.com/winzip145.exe'}, 1000);
```

This initiates a download at the specified location every second. Don't do anything dumb.

Comment: How would I change what is downloaded?

Comment: If you don't know how to change the download, I highly recommend you take some time to learn a bit of javascript or using google before asking on here.